# Perform operation when using str.find() on string c++ (no sub string)

Tags: c++, string, c++11

I have a problem when checking for commas in a .csv-file. For each row i want to perform an operation when the 10th comma is found and check the value after that comma. This value is always a number less than 9.

```
int main()
{
    string row;
    ifstream infile;
    infil.open ("file.csv");
    int sum = 0;

    while(getline(infil,row))
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < row.size() ;i++)
        {
            if(row.find(',') != std::string::npos)
            {
                sum++;
            }
            if(sum == 10)
            {
                //PERFORM OPERATION
            }
        }
    }
return 0;
}
```

The code that i have written does not work, any help?

Comment: Does not work *how*?

Comment: Put `int sum = 0;` inside your while loop.

Comment: … Perhaps because you just call `find()` over and over, which will of course only find the same comma (the first one) each time. *And* you never save the found position anywhere.

Comment: `row.find(',')` searches from the beginning of the string. You need a different overload - see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find).

Comment: @biffen - I do not have to save the position anywhere. When i have found the 10th comma i want to perform an operation. 

So my code does not work since it never finds the 10th comma. It just keeps on iterating the string.

Comment: @aekeberg If you want to find the second comma, you need to know the position of the first comma, and so on. And when you've found the tenth comma, don't you want to know its position?

Comment: @biffen Isnt it unnecessary since i just want to keep on iterating the string and for every comma just increment the 'sum'-variable. And then when i have reached 10th comma i will check the position+1 for the value and perform the operation.

Comment: @aekeberg You're asking (albeit not explicitly) why your code isn't working, and I'm telling you what's wrong with it. You just mentioned ‘position+1’, so yeah, you do want to save the position. And as I said, you can't find the nth, if you don't know n-1, i.e. where to start searching. `row.find(',')` will find *the first* comma every time. Have you tried my suggestion? Is it *not* working?

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using std::string;
using std::ifstream;
using std::cout;
using std::cerr;
using std::endl;

int main()
{
    ifstream infile;
    //infile.open("file.csv");
    infile.open("C:\\Users\\Kraemer\\Desktop\\test.csv");

    string row;
    while (getline(infile, row))
    {
        int sum = 0; //number of commas
        size_t pos = 0; //Position in row

        //As long as we didn't find 10 commas AND there is another comma in this line
        while(sum < 10 && (pos = row.find(',', pos)) != string::npos)
        {
            //Comma found
            sum++;
            //Set position behind the comma
            pos++;
        }

        //When we come here sum is always <= 10

        if(sum == 10)
        {   //10 commas found 
            cerr << "Found 10 commas" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cerr << "Did not find enough commas in line" << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You should also notice that `getline(infile, row)` will also fail when the `EOF` is in the last line that contains data. 
So you either need to check the last read line when `infile.eof()` returns `true` or make sure that the input data ends with an empty line.

To extract the digit after the tenth comma you can do something like this:

```
if (sum == 10)
{   //10 commas found 
    cerr << "Found 10 commas" << endl;

    if (pos < row.size())
    {
        char digitAsChar = row[pos];
        if (digitAsChar >= '0' && digitAsChar <= '9') // Valid digit
        {
            int digitAsInt = digitAsChar - '0'; //Convert from char to int
            cout << "Found digit " << digitAsInt << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cerr << "Character '" << digitAsChar << "' is no digit." << endl;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cerr << "10th comma is at the end of the line - no digit found" << endl;
    }
}
else
{
    cerr << "Did not find enough commas in line" << endl;
}
```

---

Input:

```
,,,,,,,,,,1
,,,,,,,,,,2
,,,,,,,,,,3
,,,,,,,,,,4
,,,,,,,,,,5
,,,,,,,,,,f
,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,8
,,,,,,,,,9
,,,,,,,10
```

Output:

```
Found 10 commas
Found digit 1
Found 10 commas
Found digit 2
Found 10 commas
Found digit 3
Found 10 commas
Found digit 4
Found 10 commas
Found digit 5
Found 10 commas
Character 'f' is no digit.
Found 10 commas
10th comma is at the end of the line - no digit found
Found 10 commas
Found digit 8
Did not find enough commas in line
Did not find enough commas in line
```

Comment: @Biffen: Updated my answer - thank you for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that

```
int main()
{
    string row;
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open ("file.csv");
    int sum = 0;

    while(getline(infile,row))
    {
        // sum = 0;  // you can reset sum at start of loop if you want,
                     //  or continue to use sum from last iteration
        int pos = row.find(','); // find first comma
        while (pos != std::string::npos)
        {
            if (++sum == 10)
            {
                //PERFORM OPERATION
                sum = 0; // reset comma count if you want
            }
            pos = row.find(',', ++pos); // find next comma (after pos)
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think you are wrong. You need to reset the `sum` every row. *"For each row [...] when the 10th comma is found"*

Comment: @Simon Kraemer Look at the comment.
It depends of how we want to count comma's. Per line or not

Answer (score 0):

Here's a somewhat minimal implementation (not including reading from file):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
  const std::string      row    = "a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,7,k,l";

  size_t                 commas = 0;
  std::string::size_type pos    = 0;

  while (++commas <= 10) {
    pos = row.find(',', pos);
    if (pos == std::string::npos) {
      // Out of commas
      break;
    } else {
      ++pos;
    }
  }

  if (pos != std::string::npos) {
    int number = std::stoi(row.substr(pos, 1) );
    std::clog << "number = " << number << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Output:

```
number = 7
```

The trick is to keep track of the position of the last found comma (which starts out as 0 before *any* comma has been found) and using it for the second argument to [`std::string::find()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find).

To expand into a ‘real’ implementation one should wrap the [`std::stoi()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) call in a `try` and in the `catch` do whatever needs done if whatever comes after the tenth comma isn't a number (or too large). And possibly put an `else` after the last block and do whatever needs done when there aren't ten commas in `row` (or the tenth comma is the last character).

Comment: it works only for 10 commas

Comment: And when pos will be string::npos, ++pos will returns (npos + 1) ie 0.
and (++pos != std::string::npos) will return true

Comment: your code will not work correctly if it is less than 10 commas.
and your code will hang in infinite loop if row will not contain any comma

Comment: @VladislavMikitich Updated. All those issues have been addressed.

Comment: @vladislavMikitich since i handle csv-files i know that the rows will contain commas, right?

Comment: @aekeberg Don't make that assumption. It'll come back and bite you.

Comment: @aekeberg rfc 4180. consists of records (typically one record per line),
with the records divided into fields separated by delimiters (typically a single reserved character such as comma, semicolon, or tab; sometimes the delimiter may include optional spaces);

Comment: @aekeberg If you expect a comma, then will commas

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution without using string::find could be like this:

```
int main() {
    string s = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11";
    int n = 0;
    int i = 0;
    for(auto c : s)
    {
        if (c == ',')
        {
            ++n;
            if (n == 10) break;
        }
        ++i;
    }

    if (n == 10)
    {
        string tmp = s.substr(i+1);
        cout << "Rest of string is: " << tmp << endl; 
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Only found " << n << endl; 
    }
    return 0;
}
```